# Convert numeric vector to 0 and 1

Tags: r

I want to convert a numeric vector to binary, i.e. values larger than zero should become 1, and zero should remain 0. For example:

```
a = c(3, 0, 10, 0)
```

...should become

```
c(1, 0, 1, 0)
```

What I tried:

```
zerone <- function(a) {  if (a > 0)    {
  a <- 1
  print(a) } else if (a == 0) { print(0) } else {FALSE} }
```

Comment: and `as.integer(a > 0)`

Comment: I dont understand your suggestion. Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logical index (`v1 > 0`) can be coerced to binary by wrapping with `+`.  The `TRUE` elements change to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.

```
+(v1 > 0)
#[1] 1 1 1 0
```

Other ways of coercion include

```
(v1 > 0) + 0L
```

Or

```
(v1 > 0) * 1
```

If we need a function

```
zerone <- function(a) {
  +(a > 0)
 }

zerone(v1)
#[1] 1 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  c(3, 8, 10, 0)
```